# cause of JSON::ParserError (784: unexpected token at '{

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I upload some files through Uppy, which saves the related JSON to a hidden form element. My create action submits this as a param called `uppyResult`. The input element looks like this once uploads are complete:

```
<input 
 name="uppyResult" 
 type="hidden" 
 value="[
  {
   "successful":[
    {"source":"Dashboard","id":"uppy-e5vuacxwuamsw4u/png-1e-image/png-56448-1625714886789","name":"E5vUACXWUAMsW4u.png","extension":"png","meta":{"relativePath":null,"name":"E5vUACXWUAMsW4u.png","type":"image/png","key":"cache/663ecb0c8cac3ea40327f625f46cecdd.png","Content-Disposition":"inline; filename=\"E5vUACXWUAMsW4u.png\"; filename*=UTF-8''E5vUACXWUAMsW4u.png","Content-Type":"image/png","policy":"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","x-amz-credential":"AKIA3JEZZFANO3B6R4TO/20210715/region/s3/aws4_request","x-amz-algorithm":"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256","x-amz-date":"20210715T213717Z","x-amz-signature":"d95631770c5ad9aad4e21c59966463b7b7e29f55946a52145ae934d8cf2d8237"},"type":"image/png","data":{},"progress":{"uploadStarted":1626385018193,"uploadComplete":true,"percentage":100,"bytesUploaded":58322,"bytesTotal":58322,"postprocess":null},"size":56448,"isRemote":false,"remote":"","preview":"blob:https://example.com/ae686b0e-1cae-4b43-9589-b7c01446b7f0","xhrUpload":{"method":"post","formData":true,"endpoint":"https://bucket.s3.region.amazonaws.com","metaFields":["key","Content-Disposition","Content-Type","policy","x-amz-credential","x-amz-algorithm","x-amz-date","x-amz-signature"],"headers":{}},"response":{"status":204,"body":{"location":null},"uploadURL":null},"uploadURL":null,"isPaused":false},
    {"source":"Dashboard","id":"uppy-91920f5bd03f91282b38941096ec4ffc/jpg-1e-image/jpeg-44471-1626247994037","name":"91920f5bd03f91282b38941096ec4ffc.jpg","extension":"jpg","meta":{"relativePath":null,"name":"91920f5bd03f91282b38941096ec4ffc.jpg","type":"image/jpeg","key":"cache/7ed930a77fb05ed135624e3c74187c84.jpg","Content-Disposition":"inline; filename=\"91920f5bd03f91282b38941096ec4ffc.jpg\"; filename*=UTF-8''91920f5bd03f91282b38941096ec4ffc.jpg","Content-Type":"image/jpeg","policy":"eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAyMS0wNy0xNVQyMjozNzoxN1oiLCJjb25kaXRpb25zIjpbeyJidWNrZXQiOiJmcmFjdGlvbmNsdWItZGV2MiJ9LHsia2V5IjoiY2FjaGUvN2VkOTMwYTc3ZmIwNWVkMTM1NjI0ZTNjNzQxODdjODQuanBnIn0seyJDb250ZW50LURpc3Bvc2l0aW9uIjoiaW5saW5lOyBmaWxlbmFtZT1cIjkxOTIwZjViZDAzZjkxMjgyYjM4OTQxMDk2ZWM0ZmZjLmpwZ1wiOyBmaWxlbmFtZSo9VVRGLTgnJzkxOTIwZjViZDAzZjkxMjgyYjM4OTQxMDk2ZWM0ZmZjLmpwZyJ9LHsiQ29udGVudC1UeXBlIjoiaW1hZ2UvanBlZyJ9LFsiY29udGVudC1sZW5ndGgtcmFuZ2UiLDAsMTA0ODU3NjBdLHsieC1hbXotY3JlZGVudGlhbCI6IkFLSUEzSkVaWkZBTk8zQjZSNFRPLzIwMjEwNzE1L3VzLXdlc3QtMS9zMy9hd3M0X3JlcXVlc3QifSx7IngtYW16LWFsZ29yaXRobSI6IkFXUzQtSE1BQy1TSEEyNTYifSx7IngtYW16LWRhdGUiOiIyMDIxMDcxNVQyMTM3MTdaIn1dfQ==","x-amz-credential":"AKIA3JEZZFANO3B6R4TO/20210715/region/s3/aws4_request","x-amz-algorithm":"AWS4-HMAC-SHA256","x-amz-date":"20210715T213717Z","x-amz-signature":"c9566b00a78bc465de654768745f39275c1a51038b98095dc9eb1e2f51d24cd2"},"type":"image/jpeg","data":{},"progress":{"uploadStarted":1626385018193,"uploadComplete":true,"percentage":100,"bytesUploaded":46446,"bytesTotal":46446,"postprocess":null},"size":44471,"isRemote":false,"remote":"","preview":"blob:https://example.com/99a4ad8f-0112-442f-ab57-fdf89eeed805","xhrUpload":{"method":"post","formData":true,"endpoint":"https://bucket.s3.region.amazonaws.com","metaFields":["key","Content-Disposition","Content-Type","policy","x-amz-credential","x-amz-algorithm","x-amz-date","x-amz-signature"],"headers":{}},"response":{"status":204,"body":{"location":null},"uploadURL":null},"uploadURL":null,"isPaused":false}
   ],
   "failed":[],
   "uploadID":"ckr5fnbkf00013g631ll6q1yk"
  }
 ]"
>
```

My create action then does this:

```
def create
 @item = current_user.owned_items.create(item_params)
 successful_results.each do |file|
  media_file_params = [{
   fileable_type: "Item",
   fileable_id: @item.id, 
   file_data: {
    id: file["meta"]["key"].sub!("cache/", "store/"),
    storage: "store",
    metadata: {
     filename: file["name"],
     size: file["size"],
     mime_type: file["type"]
    }
   }
  }]
  MediaFile.create(media_file_params)
 end
end


private
def successful_results
 uppy_result[0]['successful']
end

def uppy_result
 JSON.parse(params["uppyResult"])
end

def item_params
 params.require(:item).permit(:info)
end
```

This is throwing an error: `JSON::ParserError (784: unexpected token at '{:id=>"store/8116adea58af1759f3865d315695ed8e.png", :storage=>"store", :metadata=>{:filename=>"E5vUACXWUAMsW4u.png", :size=>56448, :mime_type=>"image/png"}}'):`

I thought that maybe the symbols were supposed to be strings, but that's definitely not it.

Comment: That is not JSON. The JSON String would look like `"{\"id\": \"store/8116adea58af1759f3865d315695ed8e.png\", \"storage\": \"store\", \"metadata\": {\"filename\": \"E5vUACXWUAMsW4u.png\", \"size\": 56448, \"mime_type\": \"image/png\"}}"`

Comment: i updated the op to show what it looks like at first. the data is inserted into the form as JSON, and then i parse it in my controller since otherwise i get `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass` errors

Comment: What does the form field for `uppyResult` look like? I think you'll find that Rails is pre-processing the field value into an `ActionController::Parameters` object so when you try to parse it as JSON it is not actually the raw string you think it is.

Comment: @rmlockerd OP updated to show input element